Incorrect values being calculated/displayed in C
I'm a beginner programmer trying to create a program that has a structure of 5 students which includes their ID, grade level, and an array of 4 test scores.
The first part of my program determines each student's average grade, which is working fine. However, when trying to calculate the average score for each test, I seem to get a large value like 132138918351343080000000.... for the 2nd test value.
#include <stdio.h>

struct student {
    long int id;
    int year_in_college;
    double test_scores[4];
};

struct student student_list[5] =
{
    {9781473, 1, {97.25, 96.5, 90, 87.5}},
    {6014552, 2, {77.8, 80.0, 81.5, 79.5}},
    {3773909, 2, {85.5, 79, 79, 90.5}},
    {8102274, 1, {88.9, 90.5, 92, 94}},
    {4582934, 1, {90, 90, 92, 89.5}}

};

const int n_students = 5;
const int n_tests = 4;

void show_student_average(struct student s){
    double student_average = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n_tests; i++){
        student_average += s.test_scores[i];
    }
    
    student_average /= n_tests;
    
    printf("%ld     %.2f\n", s.id, student_average);
}

void show_test_average(struct student s[]){
    double tests[n_tests];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n_students; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < n_tests; j++){
            tests[j] += s[i].test_scores[j];
        }
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n_tests; i++){
        double average = tests[i] / n_students;
        printf("%i  %.2f\n", i + 1, average);
    }
    
}

int main (void) {
    
    printf("  ID     Average Test Score\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n_students; i++){
        show_student_average(student_list[i]);  
    }
    
    printf("\n");
    
    printf("Test    Average Score\n");
    show_test_average(student_list);
    
}


I was expecting a value like 87.20 for the 2nd test score, but instead gives me a value of 132138918351343080000000... and I'm unsure if there's something wrong with my for loops or something else.

tests[j] is uninitialized when you are doing tests[j] += s[i].test_scores[j];. Each element of the test array should be initialized to 0 before you start adding to them. Something like double tests[n_tests] = {0}; should also do the trick.

Is there a way to get gcc to give a warning about this uninitialized array? gcc -O2 -Wall -Wextra bug.c does not print anything.

double tests[n_tests] = {0}; isn't standard C. You are not allowed to initialize VLAs but have to do it after the declaration, unless some C extension is used. I'd suggest memset(tests, 0, sizeof tests); to be sure.

Or change const int n_tests = 4 to enum { n_tests = 4 }; so that n_tests is an integer constant rather than a constant integer.  Then you can initialize the array.  In C23, you can use double tests[n_tests] = {}; on a VLA.
